# VSCode create unsaved file and add content

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In VS Code I would like to create a new document in a new editor (same window), but it need to remain unsaved. I cannot find a way to programmatically set the content of this document while it is in a unsaved state.

I have used:
`commands.executeCommand("workbench.action.files.newUntitledFile")`
but there seems to be no way to then add content to the file.

When I create a new temporary file and open it with:
`workspace.openTextDocument(path)`
The file is already saved.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try using `openTextDocument` with an `untitled` document to create a unsaved file at a given path, and then use `WorkspaceEdit` to add some text:

```js
import * as vscode from 'vscode';
import * as path from 'path';

const newFile = vscode.Uri.parse('untitled:' + path.join(vscode.workspace.rootPath, 'safsa.txt'));
vscode.workspace.openTextDocument(newFile).then(document => {
    const edit = new vscode.WorkspaceEdit();
    edit.insert(newFile, new vscode.Position(0, 0), "Hello world!");
    return vscode.workspace.applyEdit(edit).then(success => {
        if (success) {
            vscode.window.showTextDocument(document);
        } else {
            vscode.window.showInformationMessage('Error!');
        }
    });
});
```

The new file will be unsaved when first opened, but saved to the given path when a user saves it.

Hope that provides a good starting point.

Answer (score 3):

I was having some issues when the document was eventually saved using [this solution from Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41069687/13903020), but I was able to use it in combination with [DarkTrick's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69333128/13903020).

By using the default behavior of creating an empty document and making it active in the then clause.

```js
vscode.workspace.openTextDocument({
    content: newXmlContent,
    language: "xml"
}).then(newDocument => {
    vscode.window.showTextDocument(newDocument);
});
```

This allows me to create an untitled document with any content I want and show it in the editor. I was not able to give it a specific name though. This might be a limitation of creating an untitled document.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to open it in the editor, but you can create an unsaved file with content like the following:

```
vscode.workspace.openTextDocument({
  content: "your content", 
  language: "text"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

That should be supported in VSCode 1.54 (Feb. 2021), meaning the [`vscode.workspace.openTextDocument` script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41069687/6309) from [Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/306149/matt-bierner) is implemented by default:

> ### Open Editors New Untitled File action
>
> We have introduced a `New Untitled File` action in the `Open Editors` view title area.
>
> [image: New untitled file -- https://media.githubusercontent.com/media/microsoft/vscode-docs/9ffb91c3746c3dd1156970d23e22aa57ca2fe525/release-notes/images/1_54/new-untitled-file.png]

Comment: Good news, but unclear comment. See @DarkTrick's answer instead.